# react hook form: materail ui: Textfield: onSubmit, not passing Filelist in the data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to have a file input like below

```
          <Controller
            name="photo"
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
              <TextField
                {...field}
                inputRef={ref}
                fullWidth
                label="photo"
                margin="dense"
                accept="image/*"
                type="file"
                error={errors.photo ? true : false}
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
```

It gives me a value like `C:\\facepath\\filename.jpg`

How to get the FileList object in onSubmit.

I also tried:

```
          <Controller
            name="photo"
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { ref, onChange, ...field } }) => (
              <TextField
                {...field}
                inputRef={ref}
                fullWidth
                label="photo"
                margin="dense"
                accept="image/*"
                type="file"
                error={errors.photo ? true : false}
                onChange={(event) => {
                  onChange(event.target.files);
                }}
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
```

this says `Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement'`

Whereas if i use

```
<input {...register("picture")} type="file" />
```

I can see the Filelist being passed in the data.

Also

```
          <Box display="block" my={3}>
            <Controller
              name="attachments"
              control={control}
              defaultValue=""
              render={({ field }) => (
                <input
                  type="file"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    field.onChange(e.target.files);
                  }}
                  multiple
                />
              )}
            />
          </Box>
```

This also returns filelist

Comment: What's `controller` component? You can get the files with `onChange` property in `TextField` component. Maybe there is a problem in controller component. Could you share a simple sample of your code in `codesandbox`?

Comment: Controller is what react-hook-forms related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This structure for `controller` will solve the problem:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit((d, e) => console.log(d))}>
  <Controller
    type="file"
    name="photo"
    control={control}
    render={({ field }) => (
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        label="photo"
        margin="dense"
        accept="image/*"
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          field.onChange(e.target.files);
        }}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true
        }}
      />
    )}
  />
```

[image: Edit awesome-thunder-f4ox9]

Comment: whats the difference between `{ field }` and `{ field: { ref, onChange, ...field } }`

Comment: @Santhosh When you would like to access `field` on `onChange` with `{ field }`, it has all `onChange,onBlur,value,name,ref` props, But with `{ field: { ref, onChange, ...field } }`, you will spread the `field` and you can not access  `field.onChange` in the `TextField`.

Comment: But instead of `field.onChange` by using `{ field: { ref, onChange, ...field } }` I can access it as `onChange`. I am not sure whats the mistake in my code

Comment: Yes, That 's correct. Maybe it's because of `Controller`. It doesn't clear to me! :)