# material ui: how to align the Input Label properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code for input with inputlable

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="my-input">
    Photo
  </InputLabel>
  <input
    type="file"
  />
</FormControl>
```

What I see is

[image]

What I want is

[image]

I get this using:

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  label="photo"
  margin="dense"
  accept="image/*"
  type="file"
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true,
  }}
/>
```

So how can get this same effect using the previous code i.e using formcontrol, inputlable etc.

The reason i have to use that intead of textfield is [react hook form: materail ui: Textfield: onSubmit, not passing Filelist in the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037974/react-hook-form-materail-ui-textfield-onsubmit-not-passing-filelist-in-the-d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `shrink` property of `InputLabel` true and add a custom `margin`:

```
  <FormControl>
    <InputLabel shrink={true} htmlFor="my-input">
      Photo
    </InputLabel>
    <input style={{ marginTop: "15px" }} type="file" />
  </FormControl>
```

[image: Edit infallible-sanne-3t0q2]